# EditText with type numberDecimal doesn't allow values starting with 0

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText with inputType `numberDecimal`, so it should allow insertion of decimal values, like 4.2, 3.14 etc. But it doesn't allow me to insert values < 1.0, it's impossible to write 0.something, because the number doesn't appear in the EditText. The text simply cannot start with "0" for some reason.

How do I allow user to write any number larger or equal 0.0?

Tested on Android 7.0.1

EditText XML:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:maxEms="10"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
  android:textSize="16dp" 
  android:digits="0123456789." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to be working for me.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/buyET"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

For you it would look some thing like this:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:ems="10"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
  android:textSize="16dp"  />
```

Comment: Okay I figured out why it doesn't work. I had input filter in my code to allow only max. numbers before decimal point and after it, and that's what causes it. I feel really lame now, sorry for wasting your time.